# Should I use signalr hub as endpoint or invoke hub method in api controller?

Tags: c#, .net-core, endpoint, signalr-hub, clean-architecture

I use controllers and signalr in my chat microservice. I think all actions that need to invoke methods on clients through hub (like joining group, sending message, leaving group, reading message, deleting message) can be implemented in controllers or hub. But I haven't founded explanations with pros and cons about these approaches and have seen many articles where both of them are used. And I don't understand when I should create hub endpoint and when controller endpoint with hub usage inside.

Could someone explain please which approach is better and why?
Or maybe the best practice is something else like invoke hub methods in mediatr INotificationHandler?

It's example of joining to group chat.

1. Method in controller with hub usage (with this approach the class ChatHub will be empty):

```
public ChatMemberController(IMediator sender, IMapper mapper, IHubContext<ChatHub, IChatHub> chatHub, IConnectionIdProvider connectionIdProvider)
{
    _sender = sender;
    _mapper = mapper;
    _chatHub = chatHub;
    _connectionIdProvider = connectionIdProvider;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Required][FromBody] CreateChatMemberDto dto)
{
    // business logic
    CreateChatMemberCommand command = new CreateChatMemberCommand(_mapper.Map<UseCases.Dto.CreateChatMemberDto>(dto));
    int chatMemberId = await _sender.Send(command);

    // hub method
    string groupName = GetGroupName(dto.ChatId);
    await _chatHub.Clients.Group(groupName).JoinGroup(dto.UserId, dto.ChatId);

    // join hub group
    List<string> connectionIds = _connectionIdProvider.GetConnectionIds(dto.UserId);
    foreach (var connectionId in connectionIds)
    {
        await _chatHub.Groups.AddToGroupAsync(connectionId, groupName);
    }
            
    return new ObjectResult(chatMemberId) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status201Created };
}
```

2. Method in hub:

```
public async Task<int> JoinGroup([Range(1, int.MaxValue)] int chatId)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(this.Context.UserIdentifier, out int currentUserId))
        throw new Exception("UserIdentifier is not integer.");

    // business logic
    CreateChatMemberCommand command = new CreateChatMemberCommand(new CreateChatMemberDto { ChatId = chatId, UserId = currentUserId });
    int chatMemberId = await _sender.Send(command);

    // hub method 
    string groupName = this.GetGroupName(chatId);
    await this.Clients.Group(groupName).JoinGroup(currentUserId, chatId);

    // join hub group
    await this.Groups.AddToGroupAsync(this.Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

    return chatMemberId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it would be better if your application doesn't rely on signalR, I recommend designing your application to perform its primary functions using traditional API, this is because the connection to the SignalR hub is less reliable and harder to secure compared to the traditional request-response type.

it is advisable to use SignalR to send notifications not for critical tasks such as data persistence. Having a separate API makes it easier to have a backup plan in case the SignalR connection fails.